# Undefined is not a function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple question here.  Here is the code below

```js
    var num = 0;

    var increment = function() {
        return function() { num++; };
    };

    increment();
    increment();
```

However, when I tried to run it, it errors with `undefined is not a function`. How come? Isn't `increment` clearly a function?

Also, when I wrote `typeof increment`, it returns `undefined`.

When `increment()` is called twice, it should modify `num`, and become 2.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome console. (As an aside, why not simply define `var increment = function() { num++; }`?

Comment: This code looks right, although it's strange you return a function from `increment()`

Comment: I purposely made it like that a function inside function, just to test a case.  With that kind of form, how can I make the function works?

Comment: I doubt this code will throw such an error.

Comment: As @TedHopp pointed out, in which environment do you execute this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

```
> var makeIncrement = function () { var num = 0; return function () { return num++ } }
undefined
> increment = makeIncrement()
function () { return num++ }
> increment()
0
> increment()
1
```

The function has to be called (`makeIncrement()`) in order to return the inner function, which you can then assign to a variable. Once it has been assigned, you can call it and it will work as you expect.

Comment: @user122652 no problem, happy to help. By the way, I just edited to use `var num` so the `num` variable isn't visible to the rest of the code. This means that you could have several `increment` functions, each with their own independent counter.

Comment: @user122652 if your problem is solved, don't forget to accept an answer and upvote any answers that you found useful.

Comment: @user122652 you can vote for as many answers as you want. Upvoting means that you found the answer useful. To accept your favourite answer, you click the outline of a tick next to the answer. It will turn green, which means that the answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 0;
var increment = function() {
    num++;
};
increment();
increment();
```

Comment: I want to make it a function inside a function

Answer (score 0):

but what are you returning with return function()?  You should just return num.

```
    var num = 0;
    var increment = function() {
    num++
        return num; 
    };
    var something = 0;
    something = increment();
    something = increment();
alert(something);
```

Comment: I want to make it a function inside a function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the increment function does not increment the variable; it returns an inner function that would increment the variable when invoked.

As written, you would have to invoke the result of invoking the increment function:

```
increment()(); //results in num++
```

OR

```
var incrementFunction = increment(); //does not increment
incrementFunction(); //num++
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, if you want to return a function from your function, call the function returned by `increment()` :

```
var num = 0;

var increment = function() {
    return function() { num++; };
};

increment()();
increment()();
```

Or, better suited :

```
var incrementer = increment();
incrementer(); //Call this each time you want to increment num
```

Comment: I want to make it a function inside a function

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function ... exactly.  Your function "increment" returns a function, not the incremented value.  The correct way should be:
var increment = function() { return num++; };

Phil

Comment: `increment` looks like a function to me. What it returns doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to assign to `increment` the inner function, then you need to execute the outer function:

```
var increment = (function() {
    return function() { num++; };
}());
```

(This is called an [immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), or IIFE for short.) A simpler approach, of course, is:

```
var increment = function() { num++; };
```

but perhaps you have other reasons for wanting to do it in a more complicated way.

Comment: Hi Tedd. I tried it and it still says undefined is not a function

Comment: @user122652 - What environment are you using to execute this?